# Random values in header, footer and missing images

Tags: json, blob, jakarta-mail, spring-rest

We trying to read mail from SMTP server and save its details to DB as blob. Below is the sample code which we wrote.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO mail_data (msg_subject, msg_from, msg_received_date, msg_content) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new PreparedStatementSetter() {            
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            try {
                ps.setString(1, message.getSubject());
                ps.setString(2,  message.getFrom()[0].toString());
                ps.setDate(3, new Date(message.getReceivedDate().getTime()));
                lobHandler.getLobCreator().setBlobAsBinaryStream(ps, 4, message.getInputStream(),  message.getSize());
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }); 

}
```

Again the iOS developer reads it back as a json response by making API calls, we have set the response as text/html. Its having some random values as header and footer. Along with that we are not getting the images displayed.

Do let us know if we are missing some encoding or something.Seems they are company's logo as inline images, base 64 encoded.So basically for images its garbage over there.

Comment: You're not doing anything to extract any embedded images in the message.  You need to understand the structure of a [multipart/related message](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2387), extract the embedded images, and store them separately in the database.  Then you need to decide how your iOS application is going to download these images, and how the downloaded html is going to reference these images.  You will probably need to rewrite the html to change the cid: image references to something else.

Comment: Bill isn't there any way to just decode the base64 encoded strings back to images in binary form, as trying to store in blob? I can see the encoded string in response as:                  Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="image001.jpg"
 Content-Description: image001.jpg
 Content-Disposition: inline; filename="image001.jpg"; size=2207;
  creation-date="Fri, 03 Jun 2016 12:21:58 GMT";
  modification-date="Fri, 03 Jun 2016 12:21:58 GMT"
 Content-ID: <image001.jpg@01D1BDC0.9C818740>
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
 
 /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAoHBwkHBgoJCAkLCwoMDxkQDw4ODx4WFxIZ

Comment: Your call to message.getInputStream is reading the MIME content of the multipart/related message.  Instead, you need to extract each of the parts separately and store them separately.  If you do that, each of the parts will be decoded when you read it.  And again, you're going to need to decide how to make the html and associated images available to the iOS application.  You could, of course, bundle them in a multipart/related message and teach the iOS application to extract the individual parts instead of doing that on the server.

Comment: Bill thanks for the pointers!!  I extracted the images to a file location in my server and had the image path replaced in html, saved the html to DB. We carried out this task in our mail extractor program as it was a cron job. This took off some responsibility from iOS app too.